# Cancel Notification after a given time in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to cancel a notification after a given time automatically using AlarmManager.

Say for example I am setting a notification through AlarmManger at 9:00AM daily.

I would like to cancel the same notification at 09:30AM daily through AlarmManager automatically.

Hence, I was trying the the following:

The below code is set inside Notification Service

```
public class ServiceForNotification extends Service 
{
private String nText;
private Resources res;

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();

    nText = "TESTING NOTIFICATION";


        Context context = ServiceForNotification.this;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceToCancelNotification.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        RemoteViews bigView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notificationlayoutbig);
        bigView.setTextViewText(R.id.noticeText, nText);


        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(nText)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
        . setContentText ("Slide down to Expand"). setSmallIcon(R.drawable.close)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.close))
        .setTicker("TEST")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setLights(Color.MAGENTA, 500, 500).build();
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
        noti.bigContentView = bigView;
        notificationManager.notify(100, noti);

        /*18000000*/
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceToCancelNotification.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ServiceForNotification.this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am2.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 90000, contentIntent); 


    Log.e("Alarm Set","TO CANCEL");

    stopSelf();
}

}
```

I have another service called ServiceToCancelNotification..

Which has the following code:

```
public class ServiceToCancelNotification extends Service   
{ 

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();

    Log.e("Alarm","in CANCEL");

    //Cancel Notification   
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int unique_id = 100;
    nm.cancel(unique_id);

    Log.e("Alarm","Notifiy CANCEL");

    stopSelf();
  }

}
```

This ServiceToCancelNotification is not called after the alarmmanager is triggered. I am not sure why this is happening?

Can somebody help me fix this out for me?

Thanks!

Comment: What I understand is at particular time, let say at 9:00 , your particular class gets notify and shows notification. At another time, at 9:30, your class gets called and again shows notification. Is it correct behavior that I understood?

Comment: Nope. I have alarmManger in the main screen that sets alarm to 9:00 to call ServiceNotication class. This class has the notification created and also a alarmManager to cancel the notification at given time.

Comment: The cancellation of notification at the given time part is not working.

Comment: okay.. do you get that log printed which are in alarm stopping service?

Comment: Nope. That is how I knew it is not working

Comment: try using `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ServiceForNotification.this, ServiceToCancelNotification.class);`

Comment: No changes. It is still the same.

Comment: Well all seems perfect. Hope you have done all service entry properly in manifest.

Comment: Guess I solved it, but it is strange.. I set the CancelNotification alarm at the same time of setting alarm for creating notification in main activity and now it's working..

Comment: okay, that is great. One thing also need to be noted that `setExact()` method is introduced in API 19 (KitKat). So you need to use other methods, for older version of android.

Comment: Yep. I know. I was trying it out on Nexus 5. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @TheDevMan Try using a different id than 0 (zero) in `PendingIntent.getService`. I saw that it could cause problems and it's not really documented.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Alarm manager and pending intent should be global variables, and/or the instance should be passed to the cancelAlarm
AlarmManager am= null;
PendingIntent pi = null;
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
            am=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ALARM_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}


public void CancelAlarm()
    {
        am.cancel(pi);
    }

public void CancelAlarm(AlarmManager am, PendingIntent pi)
    {
        am.cancel(pi);
    }
```

Comment: This code is for cancelling your alarm at 9:30. For cancelling, in our code, we use the cancelAlarm methods as defined above.

Comment: I am not trying to cancel the alarm but I am trying cancel the notificaiton at a given time.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry, i mis-understood... I thought you try to cancel the alarm which notifies the user.

Comment: Can you please delete the answer. Thanks!